# Python ERROR SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER on code that worked few days earlier

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping

Using google-search package (https://pypi.org/project/googlesearch-python/) to open few google search results straight from cmd. Worked fine few days ago.
Now that trying to launch the code I get SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER Error

Any ideas how to fix? And if ideas what caused the error that would be interesting.

Code:

```
from googlesearch import search
import webbrowser, sys

searching_for = input(("Input search words: "))

num_results = int(input("How many results : ") or "3")

result = search(searching_for)
for i in result[:num_results]:
    webbrowser.open(i)
```

ERROR
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=tim+ferriss&num=11&hl=en (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)'))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error and fix it using the following trick.

try changing the next line of code to this:

`result = search(searching_for,proxy="http")`

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy',`

It says that you can try using HTTP on the URL. But the search library that you are using, I don't see any options for changing the protocol........

Comment: even though the documentation does not say anything about proxy, a quick glance at the source code will show you how to set a proxy

https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/blob/master/googlesearch/__init__.py#L16

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information :)